# REST API best practise for authorization

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I am developing an API using ASP.Net Web API to service a mobile app. I am using OWIN middleware with a custom OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider to handle the various grant requests for access tokens and restrict calls to authorised endpoints and this is all working fine.

I would like to restrict use of the API to the mobile app alone, using a secret key or keys. I understand this is not a 100% secure solution (possible reverse engineering / sniffing etc.), however I would like some guidance on the best practises to implement this.

The oAuth protocol already defines the use of a client id and secret, which I was thinking of using for the above purpose, however it seems the client id / secret are only checked  when the access token is requested (ValidateClientAuthentication), whereas I would like to authenticate all API calls including generic, non-user related ones.

Another option would be of passing the secret key (client id / secret) in the HTTP header and checking this in a global AuthorizationFilterAttribute. This works but I am not sure whether it is best practise. Is there a generally accepted way to handle this scenario?